# updating value on database with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, sql-update

I need some help updating the price of a wp table. I am trying to do this outside of wordpress running a php script on the server.

This the table `"wp_pzvy_postmeta"` which has these four columns:

```
meta_id        post_id         meta_key                meta_value
18538            4356           _sku                     GF-2070
18541            4356          _price                    2.343
```

I need to be able to update the meta_value 2.343 based on the meta_value GF-2070, as you can see they both have the same `Post_id (4356).`

I do ok with php but this mysql stuff really drives me crazy.
I know how to connect to the database but after that I don't know what to do.

I guess I need to be able to retrieve the post_id based on the `meta_value (GF-2070)` and then use it on the **UPDATE**

```
$sql= "update `wp_pzvy_postmeta` set meta_value=5 where meta_key ='_price' and post_id = $postid";
```

Comment: so what are you having issues with? do you want the query that select the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to work with [mysqli](https://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

1. Create an mysqli host:

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
   ```
2. Update your $sql query:

   a) Get the post_id you want:

   ```
   select post_id from wp_pzvy_postmeta where meta_key = '_sku' and meta_value = #your_value#
   ```

   b) Pick your expression :

   ```
   update wp_pzvy_postmeta set meta_value = 5 where meta_key = '_price' and post_id = #exp_a#
   ```

   c) Join everything:

   - Replace #your_value# with 'GF-2070'
   - Replace #exp_a# with a)
   - $sql = b)
3. Make your query, using the previous object:

   ```
   $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
   ```

And you're ready to go! Check [here](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for an working example :)

Comment: I think I need a little more help than this. I know how to connect to the database using mysqli, what I don't know how to use get the post_id and use it to modify the meta_value.

Comment: So, you need to get the post_id first, based on meta_value being GF-2070 and meta_key _sku, and then update the the row with that post_id and _price meta_key?

Comment: How do I give you the rating for the answer?